# multible table overlaping date trigger sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a trigger which would prevent user from adding an `ITEM_ID` with overlapping date in SQL.

Table one - `ITEM_ID` (pk), `SOMETHING`

Table two - `ITEM_ID` (fk), `SUBITEM_ID` (fk)

Table three - `SUBITEM_ID` (pk), `DATE_BEGGINING`, `DATE_ENDING`

Any ideas? I am really stuck here

Comment: ITEM_ID doesn't contain any data about dates.  Wouldn't you have to get the ITEM_ID and the SUBITEM_ID first?  SUBITEMs have the date information.  EDIT:  Why is there an Oracle tag?  Is that because they own MySQL?

Comment: You have tagged this for at least two different databases, and if by "sql" you mean Microsoft SQL Server then you've tagged it for three. Pick One.